# change smtp port from 25 to 587?

Tags: php, email, port

My ISP have blocked port 25 for sending mails from PHP, and instead have allowed port 587 or 465 to be used. how do i force php mail function to use port 587 instead of default 25? BTW : i am on OSX 10.6.6 using MAMP PRO

**UPDATE : i tried changing the settings in php.ini to this**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 587
```

as i am on mac i don't think this can be the solution for me, and it is not working after i tried. it gives me following error message.

```
May  6 20:32:25 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2822]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.159.27]:25: Operation timed out
May  6 20:32:25 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2823]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.159.27]:25: Operation timed out
May  6 20:32:25 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2827]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.159.27]:25: Operation timed out
May  6 20:32:25 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2825]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.159.27]:25: Operation timed out
May  6 20:32:25 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2828]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.159.27]:25: Operation timed out
```

you see it is still trying to connect via port 25? how do i change it in mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `smtp_port` only affects how `mail()` interacts with the server specified by `SMTP` setting.  This isn't the issue.  The issue is that:

1. You are using your local machine as the SMTP server - AND
2. Your ISP is blocking your local SMTP server (postfix) from relaying messages out to Gmail

First, [read this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=959599).  It discusses the same exact issue.  The upshot is that you need to use a different mail server, preferably your ISPs mail server.  What server and port does your ISP tell you to use for outbound mail if you want to use their Email services?  You should be able to use this from your PHP running locally just like you would an email client like Thundebird - and you **will** be able to send to Gmail.

Comment: i used gmail's smtp server and edited some postfix configuration file and it works perfectly fine. thank you for that tip.

Answer (score 3):

Set `smtp_port = 587` in your php.ini. See http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

**EDIT**

As AJ noted, this won't fix the problem if you're using your local postfix or sendmail, which you do by specifying `smtp = localhost`. Try setting that to your ISP's SMTP server address instead.

That might lead to the next problem if they also require authentication before allowing you to send mail, which many ISPs do. In that case, your best bet would be the [Pear Mail package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail). That will incidentally also allow you to specify the mail server and port in your script. From the documentation:

```
$params["host"] - The server to connect. Default is localhost.
$params["port"] - The port to connect. Default is 25.
$params["auth"] - Whether or not to use SMTP authentication. Default is FALSE.
$params["username"] - The username to use for SMTP authentication.
$params["password"] - The password to use for SMTP authentication.
```

Comment: it says Used under Windows only, but you see i am on mac, how do i change it in mac?

Comment: See the comment in the PHP manual: "Despite what this page says about the "SMTP" and "smtp_port" settings being used only under Windows, all Drupal sites use these settings to send email, regardless of which OS they're running in."

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your php.ini file (if you have access) and set `smtp_port = 587` or in your code, `ini_set('smtp_port', 587)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to override smtp_port setting with ini_set().
Should be something like this:

```
ini_set('smtp_port', 587);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using MAMP and not able to send the mail from php mail() function because of port 25 being blocked by ISP (in my case) here is some information for you to solve it. as OSX uses postfix to send mails and if you plan to use external smtp server like smtp.gmail.com which i used here is what you should be doing. you need to configure Postfix to use Gmail as a relay host

> a) Open MAMP and in postfix change the domain of outgoing mail to smtp.gmail.com
>
> b) open terminal and type `sudo vi /etc/postfix/main.cf` this will ask for your admin password enter it and it will open main.cf in vi editor
>
> c) press ctrl+f and come to the end of the file and bring the cursor one line down from the end and press **a**  , the editor will now switch to insert mode to edit the file.

in main.cf append this settings

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587

smtp_tls_security_level = verify
#smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/run/smtp_tls_session_cache

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

press **:wq** to exit vim. Back in the shell type `sudo vi /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and enter the following (substitute your gmail address and gmail password):

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 user@gmail.com:mypassword
```

again press **:wq** to save and quit the file, and run the following command

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postfix reload
```

hope this helps someone with the same problem which i faced.