# PHP mail() not working

Tags: php

I'm building a site on my home computer using MAMP. The code I'm using employs the PHP mail() function to send emails, but whenever I test it, the mails aren't getting sent.

My computer is connected to the net, but I'm wondering if there's something about local hosting that prevents mails from getting sent. I'm not getting any kind of error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: The mail() function treats OSX like a Unix system. You need a local mailserver for it to work (postfix/sendmail/etc.)

Comment: @mario We need a *close comment as answer* button :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [change smtp port from 25 to 587?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913149/change-smtp-port-from-25-to-587)

Comment: Ummmm, how is this the same question to that one about changing SMTP port numbers?  Maybe you think it has a similar answer, but even that I doubt, and that doesn't make it the same question.

Comment: @thomasrutter - There are numerous duplicates of this question on SO.  The one I chose happened to be one I had seen recently and was fresh in my mind.  I'm sure I could have done a more thorough job finding a more **exact** duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can send mail in one of two ways.

1. The first, and the default on non-Windows systems, is to use the local mail transfer agent installed on the system.  This would be "sendmail" or an application compatible with it, the most popular probably being postfix.
2. The other is to connect via SMTP to some mail server.

You will either need to install a mail transfer agent on your local system (and set it up correctly), or edit PHP's configuration to specify an SMTP server address and port.

Comment: Yup -- server's i work with run off postfix libs -- you need some library to handle this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup SMTP server in order to be able use `mail` function, or you can use [`PHPMailer` class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), with it you can avoid using mail function and setup problems, `PHPMailler` need socket extension to be loaded in order to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are things that could block locally hosted mail. For one, your ISP could block SMTP to servers other than the ISP. ask your ISP support if they block SMTP... Or try telexing so someone's MX port 25 and do you get a response?

If your ISP blocks smtp you can still send the mail, but first you must relay that email through a hosted email server like your ISP mail server. This process is called 'smart hosting' and you can search for more info.

Even if you are not blocked on port 25, many sites will refuse or lose smtp traffic that originates from a dynamic or residential IP address, so again the smart host suggestion.

Also I suggest not using the built in mail() function in PHP... Use something that replaces and improves it like http://pear.php.net/package/Mail or http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/. Again, use the SMTP method as it is way more reliable than direct sending or calling Sendmail.

It is important to confirm this problem, doing SMTP manually over telnet. That way you isolate the problem from PHP. I did ISP support for years and saw this question lots. Most people setup php and mail correctly but get stuck on a background network issue with SMTP.

If you have Wireshark installed, it can record network traffic and you might see the actual SMTP traffic, for example the remote server may be refusing your connection.  Wireshark is helpful but not required to solve this though. Good luck.