# php mail function is not working on server

Tags: php, phpmailer

the following code is not working to send mail from server:

```
if(isset($_POST['send-message'])){
    $contact_name=$_POST['contact-name'];
    $contact_email=$_POST['contact-email'];
    $contact_mobile=$_POST['contact-mobile'];
    $contact_message=$_POST['contact-message'];
    $contact_subject="Web Query by contact ".$contact_mobile;
    $contact_to="example@example.com";
    $contact_headers="From: $contact_name < $contact_email >";
    mail( $contact_to, $contact_subject, $contact_message,$contact_headers); 
}
```

please help me to find solution. this code is not working to send mail on the server. 
and please tell me the another way to send mail in php.

Comment: You checked mail in all folders in gmail? You are using php mail function, check spam folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931286/php-mail-not-working)

Comment: You should really sanitize the user input for security.

Comment: Do a var_dump( mail( $contact_to, $contact_subject, $contact_message,$contact_headers)); exit; Put this code before  mail( $contact_to, $contact_subject, $contact_message,$contact_headers); Check what message you are receiving on browser. Also enable errors if it is not already enabled.

Comment: This code is unsafe. You should really consider using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), since you tagged your question with it. You're also forging the from address so it will probably bounce or be spam filtered.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue of your SMTP config in your php.ini file.

Since you new to PHP, You can find php.ini file in your root directory of PHP installation folder and check for SMTP = and smtp_port= and change the value to

```
SMTP = your mail server e.g) mail.yourdomain.com
smtp_port = 25(check your admin for original port)
```

Comment: did you check its coming inside the if condition